# Python KafkaProducer cannot set replication factor

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

As a fact when creating a topic in kafka it is possible to set the replication factor however I was using a KafkaProducer (the kafka api for python `pip install kafka`)

I thought I could do `producer.send(...,replication-factor=3)`but then there was no option for me to do that.

Now I have only one option left is to directly create a shell script to connect to kafka to create a topic but then if the feature of python kafka is so lackluster why would I continue using it. So is there a way to set a replication factor when I am going to produce a kafka topic.

Comment: there are default replication-factor, and if kafka enable auto create topic, a topic will be created when you send message to a non-exists topic, with the default replication-factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kafka-python` does not support the Kafka Admin APIs at the moment. The only way to create topics via this client is to rely on the auto-create broker feature.

However, as you've noticed, this does not allow you to provide any topic configurations.

You can either:

- Set the replication factor in the broker config (that will apply to all topics) by setting `default.replication.factor=3` in the broker's `server.properties` file.
- Use a script (like the `kafka-topics.sh` tool) to explicitely create topics with custom settings.

The Kafka Admin APIs are still relatively new and very few clients apart from the official Java client support it.

Comment: thanks for the information I hope they added soon, I was planning to use your given option already if I cannot use kafka-python to set replication factor. But I heard there is a kafka admin in the jvm world

Comment: Yes as I said, the official Java client has support for the admin APIs. http://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html